# Rendering async promises through function components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, promise, react-functional-component

Sorry if the post is duplicated i just find examples for class components.

I have this code:

```
    export const getUniPrice = async () => {
        const pair = await Uniswap.Fetcher.fetchPairData(HOKK, Uniswap.WETH[ETH_CHAIN_ID]);
        const route = new Uniswap.Route([pair], Uniswap.WETH[ETH_CHAIN_ID]);
        const priceUni = route.midPrice.toFixed(9);
        return priceUni
    }
```

It does work, answer me the promise object:

```
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: "1106278.001628948"
```

What i would like to know is, how can i properly work with this object in order to be able to render it through function components? I'm doing something like this which obviously will not work because react doesn't render objects.

```
const Price = () => {
    const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);
    return(<>
        {state.dex === 'uni' ? getUniPrice() : state.dex === 'cake'
            ? getCakePrice() : getMDexPrice()
    }
    </>)
 }
```

Could someone give me a hint? This function is running outside a function component so I can't just use `useState`

Comment: I tried to format a bit for clarity - not sure it is 100% great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. The result of `getUnitPrice()` is a Promise, not a value, so what React does is it prints out the stringified version of that Promise. If you need the fulfilled value, you need a state value that will re-render the page if updated. Something like this:

```
const [price, setPrice] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  getUnitPrice().then((p) => setPrice(p));
}, []);

...

<div>Price: {price}</div>
```

If you're using a class component, you can initialize the state the same way like this:

```
state = {
  price: '',
}
async componentDidMount() {
  const p = await getUniPrice();
  this.setState({ price: p });
}
```

Comment: I can't do this, the function is outside a functional component so neither `useEffect` nor `useState`are avaiable.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, you are right. I can do this, i just need to import this function to a tsx file and work with it from there!

Comment: @RodrigoBurgos Added class component example as well. Please accept the answer if it resolved your problem.